# If a human just so happened to be born with wings, can anyone give me a detailed way to remove them with little pain. Hypothetically

Tags: humans

Thay don't have money, no surgical tools or experience, and not vary much time in a day to do it.

Comment: Since you want a detailed description, please provide more details: where are the wings located, how are they integrated with the anatomy and so on.

Comment: Abusing your exact words (and getting the same likely result), you could kill the patient first. Removing an arm without very good medical care is equally likely to kill the patient, and at least this way it's quick. Knowing what age this happens at may also be relevant.

Comment: Why the little pain requirement? Humans have done many operations, including amputations, with crude tools and no anaesthetics. They have used a crude wood saw and a rope to constrict the blood to amputate a leg for example. The past wasn't a happy time, but humans can survive really bad ordeals.

Comment: In other words, the answer is, "short of magic, you can't".

Comment: Rip them, fast, I was told it does magic.

Comment: @A.B. not necessarily. Drugs existed a long time, like alcohol. Blackout drunk, as quick as you can cut with something sharp through skin, sinew and possibly bone, burn the holes closed with a burning stick. I'm not saying its perfect, but surgery in those times never was. It isn't perfect in these times even. But there is an ok chance to survive for those times and possibly with relatively little pain.

Comment: It'd be a lot better if you elaborated on these wings: What kind of wings? Are them insect like (wings can be more easily cut close to the base, leaving the flight muscles alone to atrophy and part of the base structure, making it easier despite technically not removing the whole thing) or vertebrate like (there are bones, muscles and bloodvessels throughout the entire wing limb, making it a lot closer to an amputation)?

Comment: VTO Pressed to reopen, just cuz someone wants it open and it wasn't properly vtc'ed. I mean after thinking - it can get valid answers, maybe from those who know field surgery, so as restricting blood flow to wings will probably make them numb which meet the requirements, sooo even for such a poor question there is possibility for good answers. However not trilled about the q, op needs some work

Comment: @Trioxidane Maybe that would work, but they'd need an accomplice in that case.  Do they have an accomplice?  Need more details from Faultycamera.

Comment: @MolbOrg too story-based or "research that for me" question. Also, the few things OP told is that the amputating person has no medical knowledge.